# C# - Mapping object based on variable configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have a SQL query which returns a large set of fields.

I'd like to ultimately output this to a CSV file / XML file, selecting a specific subset of fields based on some configuration (which itself may reside in SQL, or a config file). The subset may be a list of the field names that apply to this configuration.

Trying to figure out how best to achieve this- I had look at using Automapper, mapping my Result Object (which contains all fields) to a dynamic object containing just the fields I want, but I am unsure if this is performant, or if Automapper can take a list of fields to map from config (say, a List of field names).

I have also considered whether to restrict the results from SQL using Entity Framework, but again am unsure on how to do this.

Comment: You can dynamically get and set the values of fields in classes using reflection.

Comment: Your's is an ETL problem and you should steer clear of AutoMapper for that reason.  Perhaps SSIS or SSDT might be more useful?  If it's really simple you can't beat LINQPad!

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion